# Regarding the prerequisites for $B \cap \bigcup _{i \in I} A_i = \bigcup _{i \in I} (B \cap A_i)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Due to Halmos:

> Thus, for instance, if ${A_i}$ is a family of subsets of $X$ and $B \subset X$, then
>   $$B \cap \bigcup _{i \in I} A_i = \bigcup _{i \in I}(B \cap A_i)$$
>   and
>   $$B \cup \bigcap _{i \in I} A_i = \bigcap _{i \in I}(B \cup A_i)$$

The principle behind these is fairly straightforward as far as I can tell; once you expand the family union/intersection in each case out to chains of primitive statements about belonging linked with an arbitrary number of $\lor$ or $\land$ connectors, the opposing operation then distributes itself across that to yield the righthand side.

What I am not clear about is why he stipulates that  ${A_i}$ is a family of subsets of $X$ and $B \subset X$. My first thought would be to prevent there being empty sets on either side of the equation which would result in vacuous truths, but this is neither necessary nor sufficient.

Let $B = \{0, 1, 2, 3\}, I = \{0, 1, 2\}, A_0 = \{4, 5\}, A_1 = \{6, 7\}, A_2 = \{8, 9\}$

Then $B \cap \bigcup _{i \in I} A_i = \{0, 1, 2, 3\} \cap \{4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9\} = \emptyset$ which would also be the result of the righthand side in this case. So it fails to prevent a vacuous truth. On the other hand,

Let $B = \{0, 1, 2, 3\}, I = \{0, 1, 2\}, A_0 = \{0, 1\}, A_1 = \{2, 3\}, A_2 = \{4, 5\}$

Then $B \cap \bigcup _{i \in I} A_i = \{0, 1, 2, 3\} \cap \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5\} = \{0, 1, 2, 3\}$

and $\bigcup _{i \in I}(B \cap A_i) = (\{0, 1, 2, 3\} \cap \{0, 1\}) \cup (\{0, 1, 2, 3\} \cap \{2, 3\}) \cup (\{0, 1, 2, 3\} \cap \{4, 5\}) = \{0, 1\} \cup \{2, 3\} \cup \emptyset = \{0, 1, 2, 3\}$

So it is also not necessary for the prevention of vacuous truth. I don't understand why Halmos sees fit to include this stipulation before introducing the equations.

Comment: Perhaps his definition of an arbitrary union/intersection assumes, for simplicity, that all the sets are contained in some universe $X$. I agree that ultimately it's probably not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that the union were taken over some very large family...then it's possible that the "union" might not be a set. (For instance, we cannot form the set of all sets...) But unions over an index set *are* well-defined if all items in the union are subsets of some fixed set $X$, for the result must be a subset of $X$.

So Halmos is including this requirement to make sure that the left and right-hand sides are well-defined entities. If the index set $I$ is small (i.e., small enough that the union is defined), then you can just take $X = B \cup \bigcup_i A_{i \in I}$ and apply the theorem.

If you're thinking "How can the union of a bunch of sets possibly not be a set?", you need to look at the definition of union. (The problem is not so much that the union may not be a set as that it may not be defined...)

Comment: Well, the union axiom in ZF tells us exactly that the union is well-defined.

Comment: Did OP say anything about ZF? I'm guessing that OP is reading "Naive Set Theory," and I can't recall where the union axiom is introduced there.